# Is the EOS Name Bidding Operational? (September 1 2018)

Tags: account-name, premium

I want to know whether there is something blocking the issuance of premium names currently in the bidding process? It has been two weeks since the last bid on the highest name and still the name has not been awarded to the winner.

Is there any plan to amend the process to speed up the bidding process? Awarding one name a day compared to the vast list of names will take a very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is currently not working.  I asked why in telegram and received no response.  I also did a brief search of the issues and did not find anything.

You can post an issue on the repo if you like: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues